# How to plot just part of the function with pgfplots, gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I have the following code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[domain = -2:2
         ,y domain = -2:2,view={0}{90}] 

\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=10},thick,domain=-2:2]
{0.5*exp(-0.2*abs(x)-0.2*abs(y))}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I'd like it to plot just the area inside a circle x^2+y^2 < 1
Any Idea?

Comment: Why not a simple circle filled?

Comment: @percuße I want it to be filled by the mentioned contour. How?

Comment: Do you mean clipping with a circle or a circle under these countours?

Comment: @percuße clipping with a circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I can't see where that extra 3.5 scaling factor comes from but this should be robust to scaling and other shifts etc.</strike>

*Edit* : the clipping path can be much simplified thanks to Christian's correction.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[domain = -2:2,y domain = -2:2,view={0}{90},grid=both] 
\pgfplotsextra{%
\clip (axis cs:0,0) circle (1 and 1); 
}
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=10},thick,domain=-2:2]{0.5*exp(-0.2*abs(x)-0.2*abs(y))}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you omit units after the circle path, the radii will be interpreted as (pgfplots!) axis units: `\clip ... circle (1 and 1);` . Note furthermore that `\pgfplotsextra` is the correct choice, but is is inserted automatically if you omit it.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Much better and obvious. I didn't know that. Thank you. By the way can you see why the need to scale with 3.5?

Comment: This is a consequence of the internal data scalings. Consequently, the 3.5 would have been wrong if the limits where from, say, -200 .. 200.